# How to group datetime in date + hour and take mean of the rows using Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Is it possible to select all the rows within the same date and hour of a datetime, then take the mean of each of the columns of all these rows and hereby create a new row with the minutes and seconds rounded to 00:00 and where the columns contains the mean values?

Our dataframe looks like the following:

```
datetime               name    temperature    humidity    wind speed
2020-02-01 00:04:12    air     8.2            87          0.4
2020-02-01 00:22:54    air     7.8            84          0.3
2020-02-01 00:47:32    air     7.5            84          0.4
2020-02-01 01:09:35    air     7.2            86          0.1
2020-02-01 01:58:02    air     6.9            80          0.0
2020-02-01 02:14:51    air     6.8            81          0.2
...
```

What we want and therefore what the dataframe should be changed to:

```
datetime               name    temperature    humidity    wind speed
2020-02-01 00:00:00    air     7.83           85          0.36
2020-02-01 01:00:00    air     7.05           83          0.05
2020-02-01 02:00:00    air     6.8            81          0.2
...
```

We imagine that a proper solution would be to use the groupby method, where we can group by date + hour, but we can't find a proper way of getting the output described above

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df.groupby({date + hour}).mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby([df.datetime.astype(str).str[:13] + ":00:00", df.name]).mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it is not giving the output described in the question

Comment: @Buster3650 I made a small change there. Did you mean the missing :00:00 in the time? If yes, my edit should solve that. Otherwise it would be nice if you could tell me where there is a difference. Thank you.

Comment: That surely grouped them up correctly, and the mistake is actually made by me. I did not include an import column, name, to the dataframe example. The column is completely deleted, when using your example. How can it be prevented? The name is always the same on every row

Comment: @Buster3650 Ah okay, I see. I made a nother change there, adding the name column to the groupby arguments. This should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

First you'd need to have your datetime field as a DatetimeIndex so it can by split to intervals automatically, since relying on string manipulations is error-prone in cases your timestamp field is malformed or the format changes.

You can do this by running:

`df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])`

Then groupby and resample your dataframe like this (`H` will do by hour):

`df.groupby('name').resample('H', on='datetime').mean()`

example:

```
data = {
    'datetime':['2020-02-01 00:04:12', '2020-02-01 00:22:54', '2020-02-01 01:22:54'],
    'temp':[10,20,30], 
    'other_metric':[100,200,300],
    'name':['air','air','air']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.groupby('name').resample('H', on='datetime').mean()
```

will turn this:

```
             datetime  temp  other_metric name
2020-02-01 00:04:12    10           100  air
2020-02-01 00:22:54    20           200  air
2020-02-01 01:22:54    30           300  air
```

into that:

```
                          temp  other_metric
name datetime
air  2020-02-01 00:00:00  15.0         150.0
     2020-02-01 01:00:00  30.0         300.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately your solution deletes string columns such as the name column described in the question

Comment: you'are right. the groupby(name) will do the job properly.